# React js - Protected Routes

Tags: reactjs

I have created a Protected Route and it works. The result is whenever I manually type the url it doesn't go inside dashboard because it is not authenticated, So you need to click Login Button first so it will goes directly to Dashboard but the problem is when I clicked login button and already in the Dashboard and refresh the page it goes back to login page again.

Here is my code for authenticate:

```
class Auth {
  constructor() {
    this.authenticated = false;
  }

  login(cb) {
    this.authenticated = true;
    cb();
  }

  logout(cb) {
    this.authenticated = false;
    cb();
  }

  isAuthenticated() {
    return this.authenticated;
  }
}

export default new Auth();
```

And for my `routes.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import Login from './login.js'
import Dashboard from './dashboard.js'
import auth from "./auth.js";

export const ProtectedRoute = ({
  component: Component,
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => {
        if (auth.isAuthenticated()) {
          return <Component {...props} />;
        } else {
          return (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/",
                state: {
                  from: props.location
                }
              }}
            />
          );
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};


const Routes = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
      <ProtectedRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
)

export default Routes
```

Is there a problem in my code? Expected result is when I click login and directed in the dashboard, Whenever I clicked refresh it will stay in the dashboard. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see at refresh your state resets and `this.authenticated` becomes `false`

Store your state in `localStorage`

Set your `localStorage` when setting your state.

```
class Auth {
  constructor() {
    this.authenticated = false;
  }


  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState( { authenticated: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("auth")) } )
  }

  login(cb) {
    this.authenticated = true;
    localStorage.setItem("auth","true")
    cb();
  }

  logout(cb) {
    this.authenticated = false;
    cb();
  }

  isAuthenticated() {
    return this.authenticated;
  }
}

export default new Auth();
```

Comment: I tried this one but still when I refresh it goes back to login page

Comment: try now, i've fixed it.

Comment: What I did is I add a condition in my ProtectedRoutes function where LocalStorage is not equal to null and it now works. Thanks for your idea

Answer (score 0):

Every time you refresh your page `new Auth()` object created with `this.authenticated = false;` So your Routes component rendering Login component `(auth.isAuthenticated() === false)`. To achieve your point you just need to persist your `Auth.authenticated` value, and in your Auth constructor check if its persisted and rehydrate its persisted value then. You can simply use Local storage to store your Auth state for example.